# Unable to create logfile minute wise in python while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

**Unable to create logfile minute wise in python while using multiprocessing**

```
import multiprocessing
import logging.handlers
import time
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing

log_file_name = "test1.log"
logging_level = logging.DEBUG
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file_name, when='M', interval=1)
handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger(log_file_name)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging_level)

def main_1():
    print("main 1")
    logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_1 ")
    time.sleep(2)
    logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_1 ")

def main_2():
    print("main 2")
    logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_2 ")
    time.sleep(2)
    logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_2 ")


def isReady():
    while (True):
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_1)
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_2)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    isReady()
```

```
**Error:**
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\user2\\WorkSapace\\MULTI\\FileTransfer_dec_06\\test1.log' -> 'D:\\venkatareddy.m\\WorkSapace\\Uniper\\FileTransfer_dec_06\\test1.log.2021-12-13'
Call stack:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 129, in _main
    return self._bootstrap(parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\user2\WorkSapace\MULTI\FileTransfer_dec_06\logging_2_new.py", line 27, in main_2
    logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_2 ")
Message: 'A Sample Log Statement main_2 '
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the logger uses a `threading.RLock` to provide *thread* safety between multiple threads logging to the same file but cannot really handle multiple processes logging to the same file.

Possibly the best solution is to create a *managed* logging object that "lives" in a separate address space owned by a subclass of `multiprocessing.BaseManager`, which starts a thread that waits for method requests to this logging object. What is actually being passed to your processes is a *proxy* object that makes the equivalent of a remote method call to the aforementioned managed logger, which then executes these calls single-threaded.

I have modified the code so that it is more likely to fail if there is a problem and also more likely to terminate.

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import logging.handlers


def init_log():
    log_file_name = "test.log"
    logging_level = logging.DEBUG
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file_name, when='M', interval=1)
    handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_file_name)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging_level)
    return logger


class LoggerManager(BaseManager):
    pass


class MyLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = init_log()

    def info(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(*args, **kwargs)

    # define other methods such as degug if required:



def main_1(logger):
    print("main 1")
    for _ in range(20):
        logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_1")

def main_2(logger):
    print("main 2")
    for _ in range(20):
        logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_2")


def isReady():
    LoggerManager.register('Logger', MyLogger)
    with LoggerManager() as manager:
        my_logger = manager.Logger()
        for _ in range(5):
            p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_1, args=(my_logger,))
            p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_2, args=(my_logger,))
            p1.start()
            p2.start()
            p1.join()
            p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    isReady()
```

An alterative is to solve the problem by subclassing `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler` and instantiating it with a `multiprocessing.RLock` instance. I then override the base class's `createLock` method by initializing the `lock` attribute with the `multiprocessing.RLock` instance. Needless to say, all processes must be using the same `multiprocessing.RLock` instance.

```py
import multiprocessing
import logging.handlers


class MyHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, lock, *args, **kwargs):
        self._mp_lock = lock # for multiprocessing "thread" safety
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def createLock(self):
        self.lock = self._mp_lock


def init_log(lock):
    global logger

    log_file_name = "test.log"
    logging_level = logging.DEBUG
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler = MyHandler(lock, log_file_name, when='M', interval=1)
    handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger(log_file_name)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging_level)

def main_1(lock):
    init_log(lock)
    print("main 1")
    for _ in range(20):
        logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_1")

def main_2(lock):
    init_log(lock)
    print("main 2")
    for _ in range(20):
        logger.info("A Sample Log Statement main_2")


def isReady():
    lock = multiprocessing.RLock()
    for _ in range(5):
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_1, args=(lock,))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_2, args=(lock,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    isReady()
```

Comment: Did either of these alternative solutions solve your problem?